# Facebook Graph API error #200 even with correct permissions

Tags: api, facebook

I'm setting up a bot to auto-post on a facebook page. But when i run the script, the graph API throws the following error:

facebook.GraphAPIError: (#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and 
either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both pages_read_engagement 
and pages_manage_posts permission with page token; If posting to a page, 
requires both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts as an admin with 
sufficient administrative permission

I give all the necessary privileges.

I try on both on group I manage and groups that I'm a member.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUgIL.png)

Hee is my pyhton code:

```
import facebook

groups=["887346338525098"]

access_token="tettrt"

msg="Apprenez l'arabe en dormant: Les 101 phrases quotidiennes les plus utiles"
link="https://youtu.be/8cZuLsYqhtA"
group="Funshoping" #887346338525098"

graph=facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=access_token)
x=graph.put_object(group, 'feed',message=msg, link=link)
```

Comment: Did you install the app in the group like the error message say?

Comment: A page, and a group, are two different things.